Bad magic number in superblock on disk
I am using Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS. I have the following disk:
Disk /dev/sdb: 3.64 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD40EZRZ-22G
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: EE5CF412-6F1B-43EC-8F1D-13F09FBABB93

Device       Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1     2048    1050623    1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sdb2  1050624 7814035455 7812984832  3.6T Linux filesystem

There is no data on the disk I need to recover, but I would like to be able to use the disk to store new files.
fsck gives the following output:
lynx@lynx-MS-7A69:/$ sudo fsck /dev/sdb
fsck from util-linux 2.37.2
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

Found a gpt partition table in /dev/sdb

Attempting to use an alternate superblock gives the following output:
lynx@lynx-MS-7A69:/$ sudo e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/sdb
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

Found a gpt partition table in /dev/sdb

fsck.ext4 produces similar output. How can I fix this disk so that I can store new files on it?

Why wonder, just reformat it. mkfs.ext4 on the partition.

@ubfan1 This fixed my problem, thank you!

Disk problems come in three flavors, firmware, hardware and software.  To ensure your firmware is up to date,check the manfacturer's site. Do some obvious hardware checks next, cables and power (sometimes an external power supply is needed in addition to what gets pulled out of the USB port). With nothing of value on the disk, or it's all backed up, (you did check that you can successfully read your backups, right?) a format will write a clean filesystem onto the disk.  Now you might run more hardware checks, like the ones the smartmontools package provides:  sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdb2  Ask for help if you cannot figure out if there are serious problems in the mass of information that gets output.
